# Как хранить координаты в т.ч. и отрицательные для константного доступа

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Имеется территория, в ней лежат объекты. У территории есть координаты: x,y,z, при чем x+y+z = 0, например 0, -1, 1 (так хранятся координаты шестиугольников).
Т.к. координаты всегда будут иметь отрицательное число среди x,y,z то просто сделать массив [,,] нельзя т.к. отрицательный индекс. Да и к тому же элемент в массиве[0,1,1] всегда будет пустым т.к. не отвечает правилу x+y+z = 0, а это перерасход памяти, но память в общем то не ключевое, ключевое - константный доступ.
Так вот как мне хранить эти территории так, чтобы я мог написать что-то вроде этого:

```
var arrObj = Territories[0,-1,1].GetAllObjOnTerritory();
```

Comment: Константный доступ по ключу (отличному от 0,1,2...) и без "дыр" - звучит как `Dictionary`. Ключ из трёх чисел можно формировать как простой конкатенацией строк, так и с помощью data-модели, состоящих из этих самых чисел

Comment: Простите за отсылку на Хабр, но там разобраны очень подробно различные представления шестиугольной сетки, и выявлены некоторые удобные закономерности. https://habr.com/post/319644/

Comment: @ilsu87 да, я по ней все и делаю)) В ней нет ответа на данный вопрос, там пишут так "Но вы можете возразить, что не хотите хранить 3 числа для координат, потому что не знаете, как хранить карту в таком виде.
Осевые координаты _типо решение_"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант первый - использовать словарик и кортежи

```
var territories = new Dictionary<Tuple<int,int,int>, string>(); 
territories.Add(Tuple.Create(0, 0, 1), "one");  
Console.WriteLine(territories[Tuple.Create(0, 0, 1)]);
```

Вывод

```
one
```

Вариант 2, упаковать это в класс с индексатором.

```
public class Territory
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class TerritoryHolder
{
    Dictionary<Tuple<int, int, int>, Territory> territories = 
                    new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int, int>, Territory>();

    public Territory this[int i, int j, int k]
    {
        get
        {
            var t = Tuple.Create(i, j, k);
            if (territories.ContainsKey(t)) return territories[t];
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            var t = Tuple.Create(i, j, k);
            territories[t] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Как юзать

```
var holder = new TerritoryHolder();
holder[0, -1, 1] = new Territory() {Name = "terra"};
Console.WriteLine(holder[0, -1, 1].Name);
```

Вывод

```
terra
```

Внутри класса с индексатором вы можете хранить все, что хотите, я словарик просто ради примера привел.

Comment: В коментах к вопросу предложили использовать не кортежи, а конкатенацию, может она будет быстрее чем всякий раз для обращения создавать новый кортеж?

Comment: @AleksandrSergeevich не знаю, может да, может нет. Но что я знаю - это то, что проблемы с производительностью надо решать когда они есть. У вас они есть?

Comment: этот запрос территории по индексу - это чуть ли не половина всех действий сервера, поэтому озаботился данным вопросом, да и в целом, я думаю на этом сайте принято делать максимально качественные ответы на вопросы. Если на вопрос что быстрее без труда можно дать ответ, то почему бы и нет. Если тяжело ответить, то ну и ладно, сам потом потестирую

Comment: Даже не потом, а вот сейчас... о результатах отпишусь.

Comment: Ну что же, протестил 5 раз, результаты всегда одни и те же, у меня на компьютере обращение 10 млн раз на прямую по индексу занимает  `00:00:00.06`; при обращении через `Tuple` : `00:00:08.47` и через конкатенацию: `00:00:03.12`. В общем она выигрывает.

Comment: @AleksandrSergeevich Я бы не спешил решать через конкатенацию. Вам известны минимальные/максимальные значения индексов? Если они невелики, то можно 3 числа преобразовать к числу математикой. Если это не подойдет, то можно попробовать заменить один словарь на вложенные словари (но это съест больше памяти). Если вам известно минимальное значение индекса, то можно попробовать преобразовать индексы к неотрицательным и потестить с 3мерным массивом Что ещё известно? Количество территорий фиксировано?

Comment: Также, если у вас так много запросов к структуре, то вероятно вам надо подумать также о многопоточности - простой словарь не является потокобезопасным

Comment: числа не велики, и количество их будет фиксированно, однако сколько точно сейчас затрудняюсь ответить. С помощью математики, имеется ввиду хэш 3х координат делать?

Comment: хм, о потокобезопасности я пока не размышлял ввиду того, что не слишком понимаю как работает хост. Я вообще только еще учусь (еще даже не джун), приложение что делаю обрабатывает хост reg.ru и вроде многопоточность он не предоставляет, но я не уверен

Comment: @AleksandrSergeevich нет, не хеш. Например, если у вас координата может быть от `-100... 100`, то есть 3 такие координаты можно преобразовать сначала к значениям `0..200`, после преобразовать в одну `var x = i * 200 * 200 + j * 200 + k`, и после эту одну использовать как ключ в словаре или индекс в массиве размером `200*200*200 + 200*200 + 200`

Comment: если у вас веб приложение на хостинге, то вы однозначно столкнетесь с многопоточным доступом, когда 2 клиента отправят один и тот же запрос одновременно

Comment: в общем, я так понял мне еще с многопоточностью и потоконебезопасным словарем повоевать придется... Ладно, тогда, думаю нам этом остановимся, спасибо.

Comment: @AleksandrSergeevich для начала определитесь с требованиями к структуре данных. Например, если вы не планируете её менять после создания, то вам может и массив подойдет (на только чтение он потокобезопасен) + вам бы определиться с требованиями к производительности - возможно, самый простой вариант вас устроит, вы же не планируете 10млн раз слать туда запросы каждую секунду

Answer (score 1):

`x+y+z = 0` - значит, z можно не хранить.

А для оставшихся двух индексов использовать двумерный массив, причём неотрицательный индекс i преобразовывать в индекс хранения `ii=2i`, а отрицательный j в `jj=1-2*j`  (обратно, если нужно: `j=(1-jj)/2`)

```
A[(X > 0) ? 2 * X : 1 - 2 * X] [(Y > 0) ? 2 * Y : 1 - 2 * Y] = Value;
```

Для коллекции вариант вычисления индекса хранения без ветвлений c битовой арифметикой:  `(X << 1) ^ (X >> 31)`

```
    for (int i = -3; i < 4; i++) {
        //int j = i << 1;  //умножили на два
        // сделали маску 1111111 или 000000
        //и инвертировали биты, если число было отрицательное
        //при этом получается (!v = 1-v)
        //j = j ^ (i >> 31);  

        int j = (i << 1) ^ (i >> 31);
        Console.WriteLine("{0:D}  {1:D}", i, j);
    }    
-3 5
-2 3
-1 1
0 0
1 2
2 4
3 6
```

Comment: Спасибо, версия интересная, что-то подобное писалось на хабре, но до меня так и не дошло как это все сделать без многоэтажных if-ов. Я к этому еще вернусь, если возникнут проблемы с производительностью или потокобезопасностью варианта со словарем.

Comment: Можно вообще без if-ов